# C++: Determine the integral conversion rank of a given integral type at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11

In a project that I am working on, I have a data structure that can store numbers of various types and needs to make guarantees about not accidentally losing precision / information.

Because standard C++ allows some lossy conversions to occur implicitly, I made a type trait that I use to determine what conversions I will allow and forbid the ones that I don't like using SFINAE.

I realized there is a subtle issue in how I am doing this though.

Here's a code excerpt:

```
// If it is between two floating point types, no truncation is allowed.
template <typename A, typename B>
struct safe_numeric<A,
                    B,
                    typename std::enable_if<(std::is_floating_point<A>::value &&
                                             std::is_floating_point<B>::value)>::type> {
  static constexpr bool value = sizeof(A) >= sizeof(B);
};
```

The intention is that, `float` can be promoted to `double` or `long double`, and `double` can be promoted to long double, but it can't get smaller.

However, using `sizeof` here is bad because on a machine where `sizeof(double) == sizeof(float)`, it would be legal to convert `double` to `float` according to this template. This will make my program non-portable -- a developer may write code that compiles and work great on their machine, and as a point of fact, not be losing precision. But on some other machine, it may just fail to compile and complain about unsafe conversions, potentially.

What I really want is to obtain the `conversion rank` as described by the standard in `[4.13] [conv.rank]`, for instance. I would like to do this for both floating point and integral types.

For instance I could just roll my own:

```
template <typename T>
struct conversion_rank;

template <>
struct conversion_rank<float> {
  static constexpr std::size_t value = 0;
};

template <>
struct conversion_rank<double> {
  static constexpr std::size_t value = 1;
};

template <>
struct conversion_rank<long double> {
  static constexpr std::size_t value = 2;
};
```

And use that metafunction instead of `sizeof`.

If I want to do this for integral types... there are many more of them.

Also there is the issue that the integral types are not required to exist, so I might want to try to detect that scenario so that the `conversion_rank` template will compile.

Is there a better / standard way to approach this? I didn't find a "conversion_rank" metafunction in the standard library, and I guess the standard doesn't actually give numeric values, it just specifies "higher" and "lower". But maybe there is something in `boost` / some other strategy that is less laborious and doesn't rely on `sizeof`?

Comment: Since you essentially want to block narrowing, just SFINAE on the well-formedness of `Dest{std::declval<Source>()}`?

Comment: That is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for, thank you!

Comment: Actually I take that back. If you want full portability, you'll have to write this with ranks. `{}` will allow `long long` to `long` on LP64.

Comment: @T.C. Is the `long long` to `long` conversion permitted in standard, or a bug in the compiler?

Comment: @user1887915 The standard (note we are talking about LP64 here, i.e., both are 64-bit integers).

Comment: @user1887915: the rule in the standard is that `{}` does not allow narrowing conversions. That's in `[dcl.init.list]`, in my copy `8.5.4.7`, at the end of the section on list initialization. The rule seems to be, for floating point to floating point conversions, it does what I said I wanted. But for integral types, it's only forbidden if the new type "cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression and (more conditions)". That means for integral types, e.g. `long long -> long` may be permitted if e.g. `sizeof(long long) == sizeof(long)`.

Comment: @T.C. and Chris Beck Thanks.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that given two integer types `T1` and `T2` with the same size but with conversion rank lower than `int`, it is impossible to determine which one has greater rank using the usual TMP techniques without hard-coding them. So if you want 100% portability you'll either have to do the hard-coding yourself or find someone to do it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I open-sourced [the component](https://github.com/cbeck88/safe-variant) that I ended up using for this.

The code that I used to make ranks is like this (see [here](https://github.com/cbeck88/safe-variant/blob/master/include/safe_variant/conversion_rank.hpp)):

```
enum class numeric_class : char { integer, character, wide_char, boolean, floating };

template <typename T, typename ENABLE = void>
struct classify_numeric;

template <typename T>
struct classify_numeric<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type> {
  static constexpr numeric_class value = numeric_class::integer;
};

#define CLASSIFY(T, C)                                                                             \
  template <>                                                                                      \
  struct classify_numeric<T, void> {                                                               \
    static constexpr numeric_class value = numeric_class::C;                                       \
  }

CLASSIFY(char, character);
CLASSIFY(signed char, character);
CLASSIFY(unsigned char, character);
CLASSIFY(char16_t, character);
CLASSIFY(char32_t, character);
CLASSIFY(wchar_t, wide_char);
CLASSIFY(bool, boolean);
CLASSIFY(float, floating);
CLASSIFY(double, floating);
CLASSIFY(long double, floating);

#undef CLASSIFY

template <typename T>
struct rank_numeric;

#define RANK(T, V)                                                                                 \
  template <>                                                                                      \
  struct rank_numeric<T> {                                                                         \
    static constexpr int value = V;                                                                \
  }

#define URANK(T, V)                                                                                \
  RANK(T, V);                                                                                      \
  RANK(unsigned T, V)

RANK(bool, 0);

RANK(signed char, -1);
URANK(char, 0);
RANK(char16_t, 1);
RANK(char32_t, 2);

URANK(short, 1);
URANK(int, 2);
URANK(long, 3);
URANK(long long, 4);

RANK(float, 0);
RANK(double, 1);
RANK(long double, 2);

#undef RANK
```